# adding items from list to existing dictionary based on key

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have this dictionary that uses a `id_num` as a key

```
{1665845 : Person(1665845, stuff)} {1294919 : Person(1294919, stuff)}
```

And I have another list that has lists containing [Id_num, date, data.....] counts.

```
[[['1665845', '2001-01-06', '28,448,615,27,705'], ['1294919', '2001-01-04', '639,118,328,413,222,491,738,389,11,372,183,650,281,643,26,398,685,171'], ['1294919', '2001-01-03', '771,373']]]
```

How can I sum up all the data belonging to the id_num and add it as a new item in the dictionary

```
{1294919 : Person(1294919, stuff, sum)}
```

Comment: How, indeed. What is Person? String? Custom object? Namedtuple? What is to be summed?

Comment: sorry I just noticed how bad that was worded, I wil fix it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean something like this:

```
s = [[['1665845', '2001-01-06', '28,448,615,27,705'], ['1294919', '2001-01-04', '639,118,328,413,222,491,738,389,11,372,183,650,281,643,26,398,685,171'], ['1294919', '2001-01-03', '771,373']]]

final_data = {int(a):Person(int(a), b, c) for a, b, c in s[0]}
```

Comment: OP mentions that they have an existing dict, and that should somehow come into the picture (I can't say for sure because of the poor wording).

Comment: sorry, i added a bit more detail to OP

Comment: I think he means, `c= sum(map(int, c.split(",")))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the existing dictionary is X and the list is Y,

```
for i in Y:
    if i[0] in Y:
        X[i[0]].sumofdata+=sum(split(i[2]))
    else:
        sum_of_data=sum(split(i[2]))
        X[i[0]]=Person(i[0], i[1],sum_of_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1665845: Person(1665845, stuff, 0), 1294919: Person(1294919, stuff, 0)}
l_key = [['1665845', '2001-01-06', '28,448,615,27,705'], ['1665845', '2001-01-10', '218,37,356,621,466,319,147,774,231,167,399,150,417,34,3'], ['1294919', '2001-01-04', '639,118,328,413,222,491,738,389,11,372,183,650,281,643,26,398,685,171'], ['1294919', '2001-01-10', '314,611,485,208,515,240,586,511,713,58,28,392,140,529,353,489,375,412,596'], ['1665845', '2001-01-04', '670,665,681,184,22,752,390,523,507,171,467,19,296,720,58,230,721,686'], ['1665845', '2001-01-02', '432,210,732,204,771,555,448,82,343'], ['1294919', '2001-01-06', '113,225,564,554,392,544,313'], ['1294919', '2001-01-05', '437,219,239,545,588,303,477,384,87,254,429,635,188,372,572,712,383'], ['1294919', '2001-01-03', '771,373'], ['1294919', '2001-01-08', '650,679,492,524,202,689,224,268,195,455,400,235,518,505']]

key_sum = {} # construct a empty dictionary
for k in l_key:
    values_sum = sum([int(val) for val in k[2].split(',')]) # sum of values stored in string in your case
    if not k[0] in key_sum:
        key_sum[k[0]] = values_sum # add key to temp dictionary if key not exist
    else:
        key_sum[k[0]] = key_sum[k[0]] + values_sum # add values in key if key exist

# key_sum will be {'1294919': 31022, '1665845': 17701} after execution of above loop

for element in key_sum:
    if int(element) in d:
        d[element] = Person(int(element), stuff, key_sum[element]) # in this case d[element will store the result which is returneed by Person
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can achieve this by collections.defaultdict

```
person_dict = {1665845 : Person(1665845,  stuff), 1294919 : Person(1294919, stuff)}  # existing dictionary
l = [['1665845', '2001-01-06', '28,448,615,27,705'], ['1665845', '2001-01-10', '218,37,356,621,466,319,147,774,231,167,399,150,417,34,3'], ['1294919', '2001-01-04', '639,118,328,413,222,491,738,389,11,372,183,650,281,643,26,398,685,171'], ['1294919', '2001-01-10', '314,611,485,208,515,240,586,511,713,58,28,392,140,529,353,489,375,412,596'], ['1665845', '2001-01-04', '670,665,681,184,22,752,390,523,507,171,467,19,296,720,58,230,721,686'], ['1665845', '2001-01-02', '432,210,732,204,771,555,448,82,343'], ['1294919', '2001-01-06', '113,225,564,554,392,544,313'], ['1294919', '2001-01-05', '437,219,239,545,588,303,477,384,87,254,429,635,188,372,572,712,383'], ['1294919', '2001-01-03', '771,373'], ['1294919', '2001-01-08', '650,679,492,524,202,689,224,268,195,455,400,235,518,505']]

from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k,_,v in l:
    d_dict[int(k)]+=sum(int(i) for i in v.split(','))
#dict(d_dict)
#{1294919: 31022, 1665845: 17701} 

for k in person_dict:
    person_dict[k] = Person(k, stuff, d_dict[k])
```

Comment: when I try in my scenario I get the error "Person' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: @JayDilla: Well if you want help with *that*, you'll have to provide complete code. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Jay Dilla, well, i think you should simplify your question without class Person to get the idea

Comment: my only problem know is my Class has more attributes than just one, so i get "_init__() missing 2 required positional arguments" when i do that